# getElementByTagName(a) for autoscroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, page-jump

What I have now is:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

I use this to get all elements with an 'a' and when I scroll it autoscrolls to the next 'a' element.

The problem with that is that I also use links (that use an `a href=""`) so sometimes it scrolls to a link instead of an `<a name="name"></a>`. Is their anyway to fix this? Like:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a name=""');
```

(this one doesnt work)

**If full code is needed I will add it below, but its probably not needed.**

```
(function () {
    var delay = false;

    $(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (delay) return;

        delay = true;
        setTimeout(function () {
            delay = false
        }, 800);

        var wd = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail;

        var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        if (wd < 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
                if (t >= window.innerHeight * 0.95) break;
            }
        }
        else {
            for (var i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
                if (t < -window.innerHeight * 0.5) break;
            }
        }
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: a[i].offsetTop
        }, 800);
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use QuerySelector for HTML 5 supporting browsers .You can check its support from http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector

**[QuerySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)**

```
document.querySelectorAll("a[name='<setname>']");
```

For older browsers use Jquery

```
$("a[name='<setname>']")
```

If you don't want to set a specific name just leave it blank. The selector is same for both JQuery and HTML 5 querySelector

```
document.querySelectorAll("a[name]");
```

or

```
$("a[name]")
```

Comment: Thanks `document.querySelectorAll("a[name]");` was what I needed, so if you use things like `name` or `href` you have to put `[....]` around it?

Answer (score 2):

Try with   [**querySelectorAll()**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp)

```
document.querySelectorAll("a[name='examplename']");
```

**find a empty**

```
document.querySelectorAll("a[name='']");
```

Comment: I want to get all `a name=''`, so how do I do that? like `a [name='*']` or something like that? sorry, I just started jquery

Comment: @Minegolfer use with  `document.querySelectorAll("a[name='']");` just do with normal empty no need a `*` see my updated answer

Comment: Sorry someone was a bit earlier then you with what I needed,
Thanks for the time.